# How to remove the mask in react-number-format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, number-formatting, react-number-format

How do I delete a form from 
When I submit a form, it takes the form of: "+7 (123) 123-1231". But I need my phone number to be sent in this form: 71231231231 .
How do I do this?

Code:

```
<Controller
         control={control}
         name="phoneNumber"
         onChange={ (event) => setPhoneNumber(event.target.value) }
         rules={{
            required: true,
            minLength : {
               value: 11,
               message: "*Заполните полностью поле телефона"
            }
         }}
         render={({
            field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
         }) => (
         <>
         <NumberFormat
             type="tel"
             format="+7 (###) ###-####" allowEmptyFormatting mask="_"
             onBlur={onBlur}
             value={phoneNumber}
             onChange={ (event) => {onChange(event.target.value); 
                         setPhoneNumber(formatNumber(event.target.value));
                         console.log(event)
             }}
          />
          <WarrningError>{errors?.phoneNumber && <p>{errors?.phoneNumber?.message || `*Необходимо заполнить поле "Номер телефона"`}</p>}</WarrningError>
          </>
          )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onValueChange={(values) => {
    const { formattedValue, value } = values;
    // formattedValue = $2,223
    // value ie, 2223
    this.setState({ profit: formattedValue });
  }}
```

Comment: Not really sure why this needed to be a Q&A since it's discussed in [their documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)

Comment: @evolutionxbox- I wasn't able to find it the first time, so I decided to ask, but after reading even better, I found it) My bad